# NPE using 2D object array java

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am getting a NPE in this code. I tried to initilialize each index but doesn't seem to work either. Can you please point out what is wrong? Thanks!

```
    package com.js.teachEnglish;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;

public class Piggy_Panel extends JPanel {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int number_lines = getLines(Helper.piggybackResource.getPath());

    protected JLabel title_Label = new JLabel("Piggyback words");

    protected ImageIcon button_image = new ImageIcon(Helper.soundIconResource);

    protected JButton title_Button = new JButton(button_image);

    protected JPanel titlePanel = new JPanel();

    protected JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(this);

    protected JLabel[] label_group = new JLabel[number_lines];
    protected JButton[] button_group = new JButton[number_lines];

    protected String[] information = new String[number_lines];

    // Table information
    protected String[] col_titles = new String[] {"",""};
    protected Object[][] table_contents = new Object[number_lines][];

    protected JTable table;

    // constructor
    public Piggy_Panel() {
        setLayout(new GridLayout(number_lines+1,1));

        // scroll pane
        pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        // getting the information
        readInformation();

        /*
         * adding the title seperately
         * and also adding characteristics for the label
         *  */

        titlePanel = new JPanel();
        titlePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        // adding the characteristics for the label
        title_Label.setFont(new Font("Arial",Font.PLAIN,36));

        titlePanel.add(title_Label);
        titlePanel.add(title_Button);

        add(titlePanel);

        // calling the ini_labels_buttons() to initlialise the buttons and labels
        ini_labels_buttons();

        // fill the object[][] in
        fill_table();

        // initialising table and adding specific characteristics
        table = new JTable(table_contents, col_titles);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setShowHorizontalLines(false);
        table.setShowVerticalLines(false);

        add(table);


        // calling the ini_panel_group() to add everything

        title_Button.addActionListener(new buttonListener());


    }

    // will read the information from the file
    public String[] readInformation() {
        try {
            String line = null;

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(Helper.piggybackResource.getPath()));

            int i = 0;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                information[i] = line;
                i++;
            }

            return information;

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;

    }

    // will put out the sound
    // This will output the sound if a button is clicked
    class buttonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();

            String sayDynamicPath = Helper.sayDynamicResource.getPath() + " ";

            if(button.equals(title_Button)) {
                try {
                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sayDynamicPath +
                            title_Label.getText());
                }catch(Exception ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,""+ex,"Unable to produce sound",
                            JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Initialising the JLabels and JButtons and also adding the relevant functions
    // these include icons and information
    public void ini_labels_buttons() {

        // initialising the buttons first
        for (int i = 0; i < button_group.length; i++) {
            button_group[i] = new JButton(button_image);
        }

        // initialising the labels
        for (int i = 0; i < label_group.length; i++) {
            label_group[i] = new JLabel(information[i]);
        }

    }

    public void fill_table() {
        // fill in the first col
        for (int i = 0; i < table_contents.length; i++) {
            table_contents[i][0] = information[i]; // null pointer here
        }

        // fill in the second the col
        for(int j = 0;j < table_contents.length;j++) {
            table_contents[j][1] = button_group[j];
        }
    }

    // this method will get the number of lines and then send it back
    // to the label group
    public int getLines(String path) {
        int n = 0;

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            String line = "";

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                n++;
            }

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return n;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the line # at which you get the NPE.  If you have an array, you should realize that allocating an array of references initializes all to null unless you set them to point to an object.  Sounds like you missed one.  A debugger should sort you out faster than asking here.

Comment: It's line 162. I don't know how to use debugger.

Comment: Open up your editor, turn on line numbers, and go to line 162.  One of the references you're using is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looing at the NPE's stacktrace would be useful. ;)

This creates an array of references to arrays, not arrays of arrays.

```
protected Object[][] table_contents = new Object[number_lines][];
```

This means that

```
table_contents[i][0] = information[i];
```

should throw an NPE because table_contents[i] will be `null`. Looking in a debugger will confirm this.

The simplest solution is to create an array or arrays with

```
protected Object[][] table_contents = new Object[number_lines][2];
```

BTW I would use one loop instead of two.

Comment: Hi, How do you use the debugger to find these sort of things, can you point me to a tutorial that you are aware of? Thanks!

Comment: The simplest way is to add a breakpoint on NullPointerException and run the Debug in your IDE (next to Run) How you do that depends on your IDE.